# Live Template fore Intellij IDEA for Iterating through Map

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets, live-templates

We can iterate through collection easily by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, [image]

And then I wanted to create such template for iterating through map:
I wrote these lines to *template text* box:

```
for (Map.Entry<$ELEMENT_TYPE$> $VAR$ : $SELECTION$.entrySet()) {
  $END$
}
```

Now it is generating these codes:

```
 HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    for (Map.Entry<Object> objectEntry : map.entrySet()) {

    }
```

`Map.Entry<Object>` should be `Map.Entry<String,Object>`. I cannot find a way to introduce variable correctly. How can I do that?

Comment: I use `iter` + `<tab>` and select `map.entrySet()` Do you need to create a new template to do this? If so you can look at how this one is implemented already.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is easier if you just type `iter` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You will get a drop-down and there you can choose `map.entrySet()` and it will give you:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> stringObjectEntry : map.entrySet()) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To view a list of live template available: `Ctrl + J` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

From there you will have list of live template, **iter** (for each loop) will be on the list.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this, it works in 1 step. I also like having the `key` and `value` in there already, but those can be omitted:

```
for (Map.Entry<$KEY_TYPE$, $VALUE_TYPE$> $PAIR$ : $ITERABLE_TYPE$.entrySet()) {
    $KEY_TYPE$ key = $PAIR$.getKey();
    $VALUE_TYPE$ value = $PAIR$.getValue();
    $END$
}
```

Variables:

- KEY_TYPE: `guessElementType(iterableVariable())`
- VALUE_TYPE: `regularExpression(typeOfVariable(ITERABLE_TYPE),"^.*,(.*)>$", "$1")`
- PAIR: `suggestVariableName()`
- ITERABLE_TYPE: `variableOfType("java.util.Map")`

The [large amount of variables and functions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html) make the Live Templates a powerful tool. In VALUE_TYPE, I am using a regular expression to get the `ValueType` out of `Map<KeyType, ValueType>`. I tried a lot of "cleaner" approaches, but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you just type `itm` and then `Tab`.

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) {
     String key = entry.getKey();
     List<String> value = entry.getValue();   
 }
```